# How can you get a zipfile link embedded in an email to download?

Tags: c#, email, razor, sendgrid

The following code creates a link that contains a zip file in a blob storage container:

```
        public string GetPublicUrl(string containerName, string blobName, DateTime expiry, BlobSasPermissions permissions = BlobSasPermissions.Read, string fileName = null, bool isAttachment = false)
        {
            var containerClient = GetContainerClient(containerName);
            var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);
            if (!blobClient.CanGenerateSasUri) return null;
            var sas = blobClient!.GenerateSasUri
            (
                new BlobSasBuilder(BlobSasPermissions.Read, expiry)
                {
                    ContentDisposition = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? $"{(isAttachment ? "attachment; " : "")}filename={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName)}; filename*=UTF-8''{Uri.EscapeDataString(fileName)}" : null,
                    CacheControl = "no-cache"
                }
            );
            return sas.ToString();
        }
```

I then go ahead and embed this link into an email I send through Sendgrid.

The issue I am having is that the link created does not open and download the file on all machines, especially mac computers. A new tab opens but then immediately closes without the file downloading.

When I copy the link and paste it directly into a new tab, the zip file downloads.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After much head-banging, adding `clicktracking=off` to the `<a>` tag in the email worked. So now the link looks like this:

`<a href="@Model.Url" clicktracking=off>Files</a>`

Im unsure why this works but hey!